# Is it still valid when the variable passed to `std::async` is out of scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdasync

Is the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/16d76EYf4) below legal? What worries me is when `factorial` is invoked the `fut_num` may be already out of scope.

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//int factorial(std::future<int> fut) //works, because there is a move constructor
int factorial(std::future<int>&& fut)
{
    int res = 1;
    int num = fut.get();

    for(int i=num; i>1; i--)
    {
        res *= i;
    }

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> prs;
    std::vector<std::future<int>> vec;

    {
        std::future<int> fut_num{prs.get_future()};
        vec.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, factorial, std::move(fut_num)));
    }  //`fut_num` is out of range now.
    
    prs.set_value(5);

    for(auto& fut: vec)
    {
        std::cout << fut.get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And the same question about similar [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/z9do7e83e):

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//int factorial(std::future<int> fut) //works, because there is a move constructor
int factorial(std::future<int>& fut)
{
    int res = 1;
    int num = fut.get();

    for(int i=num; i>1; i--)
    {
        res *= i;
    }

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> prs;
    std::vector<std::future<int>> vec;

    {
        std::future<int> fut_num{prs.get_future()};
        vec.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, factorial, std::ref(fut_num)));
    }  //`fut_num` is out of range now.
    
    prs.set_value(5);

    for(auto& fut: vec)
    {
        std::cout << fut.get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**My two cents about these code snippets**:

1.The former code snippet is legal, since `std::async` copies `std::move(fut_num)`(i.e. `std::move(fut_num)` is passed by value to `std::async`). So there is a local `fut_num` when `fcatorical` is called.

2.The latter one is illegal, since `fut_num` is passed as a reference to `std::async`. When `fut_num` is out of scope, it's illegal to call functions which uses `fut_num`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I updated the post, adding the session named `My two cents about these code snippets`. How do you think about it?

Comment: Your edit is basically the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is fine, the second one is not.

---

`std::async` with `std::launch::async` uses the same procedure of invoking the thread function as the constructor of `std::thread` does. Both effectively execute

```
std::invoke(auto(std::forward<F>(f)), auto(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
```

in the new thread, but with the `auto(...)` constructions executing in the context of the calling thread.

Here `F`/`Args...` are the (other) template parameters with corresponding forwarding-reference function parameters `F&& f`/`Args&&... args` and `auto` has the new C++23 meaning which creates a prvalue/temporary of the decayed argument's type from the argument.

See [[futures.async]/4.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/futures.async#4.1).

This means there will be unnamed copies constructed for all arguments which live in the new thread until after the thread function invocation returns.

So with `std::move(fut_num)`, there will actually be another `std::future<int>` object which will be move-constructed from `fut_num` and live until the thread ends execution. `factorial` will be passed a reference to this unnamed object.

---

With `std::ref(fut_num)` you are explicitly by-passing this mechanism protecting you from passing references to the objects in the constructing thread.

The constructor will still make a decayed copy of type `std::reference_wrapper<std::future<int>>` from the argument, but that object will just contain a reference referring to `fut_num` in the main thread.

`std::invoke` will then unwrap the `std::reference_wrapper` before passing to `factorial` and the `fut` argument will refer to `fut_num` in the main thread, which is then destroyed without any synchronization, causing undefined behavior as it is also accessed in the `factorial` function.

---

It either case it doesn't matter whether `factorial` takes the argument by-reference or by-value. Nothing about the above reasoning changes.